# Is it possible to call rails model methods from rack middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

```
def inside_rack_middleware
  MyModel.update_attributes(:ip => request.ip)
  redirect somewhere else
end
```

is that possible?

Comment: does the question suck or no one knows?

Answer (score 3):

got the answear via @supercoco9 on twitter, "if your middleware is in a rack/rails stack you can use the models directly via AR"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access your AR models from within your middleware. I added byebug in my middleware and was able to access my models.

EDIT:- So, I started writing a Rack middleware to use in my Rails app. I tried to access my AR model in the middleware but its behaviour was quite funny. Everything would go fine for the first request served after a fresh server start. But any request that came after that resulted in error:-

> A copy of MyMiddleware has been removed from the module tree but is still active

This error vanished as soon as I stopped accessing the AR model from within the middleware.
I have just started with Ruby/Rails so I don't know the specific terms in Ruby/Rails/Rack world. But in simple words, all I can say is that Rack middleware is just a kind of plug & play library which anyone can use in any Rack app. So we shouldn't be dependent on ay kind of Rails objects inside our Middleware.